# Ajuda no z-index

Tags: css

Boa Noite,

Estou a desenvolver um site mas já estou farto de tentar e nada, a questão é a seguinte:

- Tenho uma caixa de contacto fixa no lado direito mas não aparece, pelo que li tenho que definir o z-index, adaptei um script que comprei na themeforest mas ele não aparece no site.

www.agemper.pt/novo/index.html

Codigo Basico do script por defeito

```
#slideit {
    z-index:999999; /* Keep the item above all other elements on the page */
    position:fixed;
    width: auto; /* Width of the wrapper of the section. Adjust this value if you want wider elements */
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; /* Vertical position of the elements */
    right: 0; /* Horizontal position of the elements */
}
```

Abraços

Comment: coloque algum código... pq assim n da pra resolver, a não ser que voce tenha esquecido de colocar position: absolute; onde tem o z-index

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o html e css da caixa que não aparece

Comment: coloque o html, e css do div pai tbm

Comment: O z-index está OK, o problema é que está com largura zero (você definiu como "auto", e nesse contexto não está servindo para nada). Este tipo de problema se visualiza com facilidade pelo inspetor do browser. Fica a sugestão de ao fazer perguntas, prover ao menos um [mcve] na postagem. Em muitos casos, ao fazer o exemplo tentando reproduzir o problema, você já encontra o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Se ta fixo ela não pode ser proporcional ou automático o valor de width ou height, porque ele nao vai se basear em nada pra ser auto ou com porcentagem. Mude o valor para px, exemplo:

```
 #slideit {
    z-index:999999;
    position:fixed;
    width: auto; 
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; /* Vertical position of the elements */
    right: 0; /* Horizontal position of the elements */
}
```

Outro detalhe, que não sei se é assim mesmo ou comportamento, mas acho(só acho)que voce quer ele no rodapé, então coloque ele como bottom:0, mas se for pra ser no topo da página ta certo.
 Mais um detalhe, para 'enxergar' ele, coloque um background na div, de preferência com cor pra dar contraste até voce conseguir colocar onde deseja, desta forma ficaria:

```
#slideit {
        z-index:999999;
        position:fixed;
        width: 200px; 
        height: 100px;
        bottom: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        background: #000;
    }
```

Comment: Resolvido. Muito Obrigado